# Reverse proxy to invoke complex authorization logic?

Tags: java, authentication, nginx, reverse-proxy, haproxy

So I have a bunch of apps that have their own authorization logic. And I need to make these apps support a new authorization logic (so both apps will run in production, with 2 ways to authentic, for 2 kinds of users, in their own isolated environments). So instead of going and forking them or retrofitting them to support both authorizations, it would be better push authentication validation out of the application itself. For example, instead of a given app having the typical session filters (eg: j2ee filters, angular's "can_activate" callback) to determine if the user is logged in, just push that logic into a reverse proxy. The reverse proxy acts as a bouncer, only letting traffic that has the right authorization (eg: in a cookie, header, etc) to go through to the intended app, otherwise it 302 redirects them to login.

So, is there a reverse proxy that will allow me to route/url-rewrite incoming requests? But also allow me to invoke custom/complex logic (preferably written in Java) to invoke calls to AWS Cognito and MySQL (ie: just invoke java code). I know HA proxy would work great, but there re-write rules do not allow invoking custom code.

Answer (score 0):

Found what I was looking for, which is to protect resources using oidc, [already exists as an apache module](https://github.com/zmartzone/mod_auth_openidc/blob/master/auth_openidc.conf)

Of course, if one needed, they could [write their own apache module](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/developer/modguide.html) (in c language) to invoke their own custom logic.

Comment: This is a borderline [link-only answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231). You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference.

Comment: Fixed it up a bit by adding another link on how to write an apache module. I don't want to re-iterate all that is said in there. I just wanted to point out that is possible, for design consideration reasons.